# How do the tag master hats work?

Tags: support, winterbash

I mean the "<insert game name> master" hats. Their description says this:

> 3 upvoted questions or answers tagged "x"

That's a bit ambiguous. Does that mean either 3 upvoted questions *or* 3 upvoted answers, or questions and answers combined?

Comment: I have a few of these hats, so I can confirm that you can get either 3 upvoted questions, 3 upvoted answers, or any combination of questions and answers that total 3.  4 shall not be counted, and 5 is right out.

Comment: @agent86 So if it's questions and answers combined, then something is broken because I should have a Minecraft hat if that was the case.

Comment: @lunboks Does the hat-giving service run more often than every couple hours? Maybe it needs to be restarted again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means questions and answers combined.

Comment: Yes, yes it does. For the record, [this (confirmed) bug](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3713/minecraft-hat-not-awarding) I encountered is why I asked.